# Link HTML sheet to another HTML sheet

Tags: php, html, css, safari

I came across a problem when I tested my page with different browsers. I got it working for the most used browsers(IE,Chrome,Opera,Firefox) but not for Safari. Safari needs a whole different div layout and CSS layout. so I tried linking a HTML Sheet when safari opens the page. the only thing I get when I open it in safari is only my HTML code for the site and not the site itself.
Anyone who can help me solve this problem?

PHP code:

```
<?php 
    add_filter('body_class','browser_body_class');
    function browser_body_class($classes) {
        global $is_lynx, $is_gecko, $is_IE, $is_opera, $is_NS4, $is_safari, $is_chrome, $is_ip;
        if($is_safari) {
            echo '<link href="AVSales Web Page.html" />';   
        }
    }
?>
```

Need more of my code to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too stupid names of sites... you cant name the site AVSales Web Page.html Try to name it avsaleswebpage.html , or AVSales_web_page.html .

Your site must be with .php extension, not the html... so rename index.html to index.php

Comment: Changed the name's. the site had a .php extension  already. nothing changed, the result is still the same. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: What are you trying to link? You can link only .css files in <head> before <body>. Favicon and a few another things... you cant link the html document... If your problem is only in safari, the fault is't in PHP code. PHP is server side, so it gives always the same output for each browser

Comment: well. i got most things sorted out now so it works in Safari and all the other browsers. by setting divs up diffrently. but it was only safari having a problem placing the objects in the right place. when i try to open the php in safari it gives only text now. any clue what that is about?